# "Use email attribute from Contacts" - Can't choose non-system email

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a Data Extension with an EmailAddress field connected directly to Contacts via an Attribute Group.

This is the main way I am inserting email addresses into SFMC. I do not currently have a way to update the system email address on the contact.

In the Journey Builder settings, it only allows me to choose the system email address
[image]

What am I missing here? Why can I not select the EmailAddress connected to the contact via a data extension?

Answer (score 2):

Only Data Extensions linked as a [Population](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_create_a_population.htm&type=5) will be selectable in this configuration screen. The most straight forward way is to use the email address from the Entry Source DE